# Ayuda con Script para saltar en Unity 3D

Tags: c#, script, unity, 3d

La cosa es que soy muy novato y estoy haciendo un juego para una asignatura de la carrera y no encuentro forma de hacer que el maldito Player salte. Se mueve en los ejes X y Z, pero no consigo que salte. Agradecería mucho si alguien me encuentra el fallo.
Por otro lado, tampoco hace caso a la parte del código que le manda rotar en función a donde apunte el ratón. Esto es secundario, si me lo resolviesen se lo agradecería.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed=15.0f;

Vector3 movement;
Animator anim;
Rigidbody playerRigidbody;


int floorMask;
float CamRayLength = 100f;

private void Awake()
{
floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Floor");
anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
playerRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

}
void FixedUpdate()
{
float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
Move(h, v);
Turning();
Animating(h, v);

}
```

***Intento que salte con este código, pero no funciona***

```
 void Update()
 {
 if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
 playerRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 100); 

 }

void Move(float h, float v)
{
movement.Set(h, 0f, v);

movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
}
```

***Esta es la parte que se supone hace que el 
                                 player rote según donde apunte el ratón***

```
void Turning()
{                             

Ray camRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);


RaycastHit floorHit;


if (Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit, CamRayLength, floorMask))
{

Vector3 playerToMouse = floorHit.point - transform.position;


playerToMouse.y = 0f;


 Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerToMouse);
playerRigidbody.MoveRotation(newRotation);
}
 }

void Animating(float h, float v)
{

bool walking = h != 0f || v != 0f;


anim.SetBool("IsWalking", walking);
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
 {


anim.SetTrigger("Jumping");

}



}

}
```

Comment: Siento ponerlo asi de desordenado. Soy nuevo en esta plataforma y no se muy bien como ponerlo ordenado

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/340033/help-with-a-simple-jump-script.html

Answer (score 0):

Analizando la sección de tu codigo puedo hacer una observación.

```
void Update()
 {
 if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
 playerRigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 100); 

 }

void Move(float h, float v)
{
movement.Set(h, 0f, v);

movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

playerRigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + movement);
}
```

En esta sección de código en específico es conveniente que al establecer nuevos valores para la velocidad de un objeto en un Vector3 se conserven los valores que no se desean modificar de la siguiente forma.

```
movement.Set(h,  playerRigidbody.velocity.y , v);
```

Lo que sucede es que le agregas la fuerza en *y*, pero la siguiente vez que actualizas mandas a llamar a la función denuevo y agregas 0f a su eje y nuevamente, lo cual impide que se mueva, pues la actualización es al casi al instante.

-Gremin

Comment: por favor no publiques múltiples respuestas, solo has una; borra la otra y dale editar a la que dejes para agregar lo que falte